# Kubernetes readiness(http) probe is failing but liveness (http) is working fine without readiness

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes readiness (http) probe is failing, however liveness (http) is working fine without readiness.
Using the following, tested with different initialDelaySeconds.

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
```

```
livenessProbe: 
  httpGet: 
    path: /healthz 
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 120 
  periodSeconds: 10
```

Comment: How is your _livenessProbe_ configured?

Comment: Add more details on what failure is seen .. livenes probe details etc ..

Comment: livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      periodSeconds: 10

Comment: Getting a connection refused error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine after increasing the initialDelaySeconds to 150 seconds.
As the Container is taking longer than 120 seconds to come up sometimes and few times it is under 120 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The `readiness` and `liveness` probes serve slightly different purposes:

- the [`readiness`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) probe controls whether the pod IP is included in the
  list of endpoints for a service, and so also whether a target for a
  route when it is exposed via an external URL;
- the [`liveness`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) probe determines whether a pod is still running
  normally or whether it should be restarted.

Theoretically situation like you describe could happened if something wrong with exposing of your service for example. Have a look at the best practices [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes), also you can find some extra information [here](https://medium.com/@AADota/kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes-difference-1b659c369e17).